# Object's property shows different value after I stored the object into a variable

Tags: javascript, sapui5

My object has a property `flightbooking`, which is also an object. When I `console.log` the whole object, its `flightbooking` property is equal to:

```
flightbooking:
  __ref: "BookingCollection(carrid='AZ',connid='0555',fldate=datetime'2018-12-13T00%3A00%3A00',bookid='00000483')"
  __proto__: Object
```

Now, I want to get that value of `flightbooking` property into a variable or I want to at least be able to `console.log` that value.

The problem is whenever I store my object into a variable `myObj` and then I try to `console.log(myObj.flightbooking)`, the value of `flightbooking` unexpectedly changes to this:

```
{__deferred: {…}}
  __deferred: {uri: "http://sapsmddb.mydomain.com/sap/opu/odata/…=datetime'2018-12-13T00%3A00%3A00')/flightbooking"}
  __proto__: Object
```

This is from my `Detail.controller.js` file:

```
var myObj = window.detail.getView().getModel().oData["FlightCollection(carrid='" + this._carrid + "',connid='" + this._connid + "',fldate=datetime'" + this._fldate + "')"];
console.log("myObj: ", myObj);
console.log("myObj.flightbooking: ", myObj.flightbooking);
```

Comment: oData is a 'private' property and you cannot rely on its contents, what you see as "__ref" is an internal representation of association. 
Use ...getView().getModel().read(...) instead.

Comment: Exactly as @slkorolev says. Somewhere in the documentation SAP tells us: "Don't use private and protected methods or properties of UI5."